# Subadditive function with special growth

Tags: real-analysis, convexity

Related to one of my previous question (for which I have received an answer, thanks) I have the following new one. Maybe I am describing the empty set but not being a specialist at all of the domain I prefer to ask the community.  I'm looking for a real valued function $g(x)$  with the following behaviour:

$g(x)$ defined $[-\infty,0]$ with first derivative on $(-\infty,0)$ 
 
$g(x)$ sub-additive on $(-\infty,+\infty)$ 
$e^{x} \cdot g(x)$ convex 
$g(0) < +\infty$
$\frac{g(x)}{x} \rightarrow -\infty$ when $x \rightarrow -\infty$

Hope I'm clear enough. 
 
Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Such a function $g$ does not exist. Indeed, by the [subadditivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity) of $g$, we have $g(-n)\le ng(-1)$ for all natural $n$, whence
$$\frac{g(-n)}{-n}\ge-g(-1)>-\infty. 
$$
So, the condition $\frac{g(x)}{x} \rightarrow -\infty$ when $x \rightarrow -\infty$ cannot hold.

(The inequality $-g(-1)>-\infty$ takes place because $g$ has a derivative on $(-\infty,0)$ and hence is finite on $(-\infty,0)$.)

Comment: Oh! yes of course thanks a lot Iosif. Do you think that if I remove this condition of growth there is a better chance to find candidate(s) ?
Moreover I can maybe also weaken the condition on the derivative to have only left or right derivatives

Comment: @GianfrancoOLDANI : Yes, if the growth condition is removed and other conditions are relaxed, then it could be possible for the class of the functions to be nonempty.